# Thread.sleep for animation (Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

I am using sprite and Animated sprite. I used Animated sprite for 16 frames. For left,right,up,down and last 4 frames blast animation.

```
//animSprite.setCurrentTileIndex(leftCount);
```

When animated Sprite collide with sprite .. I want to show last 4 frames for 5 sec. How to make using andengine. I tried with Thread.sleep but its not working.

//For update i am using

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
            @Override 
            public void reset() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {    
              checkCollision();
}
```

I able get last 4 frames number in logcat. But screen not updated..

How to refresh the scene .

```
checkCollision()

{

if(sprite.collidesWith(animSprite))

  try
                   {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                                         

                        animSprite.setCurrentTileIndex(animBlast);                    

                        Log.v("balst",""+animBlast);

                         animBlast++;

                         if (animBlast> 15) {

                             animBlast= 12;

                         }

                         Thread.sleep(10);

                    }

                   }
                   catch (Exception e) {

                       // e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `AnimatedSprite` you have an `sprite.animate(long[] pFrameDurations, int pFirstTileIndex, int pLastTileIndex, int loopCount)` method, that does a `loopCount` of loops of frame changes from `pFirstTileIndex` to `pLastTileIndex` with frame durations also defined. I feel this is what you're looking for.

Comment: ya its working fine thanks , In andengine is possible to use Thread.sleep method

Comment: @JohnRaja, haven't ever felt need for this

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `Thread.sleep()` in the update thread, since that will block all other updates and redrawing. Instead look into the `AnimatedSprite.animate()` methods as Egor said.

If you want something similar to sleep, then use the `TimerHandler`s in AndEngine. Change `false` to `true` to get a repeating timer.

```
TimerHandler my_timer = new TimerHandler(10, false,
    new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            // Do your thing    
        }
});
scene.registerUpdateHandler(my_timer);
```